# dart HttpClient with subscription causes delayed shutdown

Tags: dart, httpclient, subscription

I have a dart app that is using HttpClient with a listener.

Whilst the below sample doesn't show it, I'm using the listener to report progress messages which I've left out to make the sample simpler.

If you run the app it runs 'to completion' but then doesn't shutdown immediately.
You can see this if you run the app from the cli or in a debugger.

With some experimentation it appears that the listener isn't draining down the request but I can't see why this isn't happening.

The assert on line 35 passes which indicates that the entire file has been downloaded.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

String baseURl =
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bsutton/dcli/master/test/src/functions/fetch_downloads';

void main() async {
  final completer = Completer<void>();
  var saveToPath = '/tmp/sample.acc';

  var fetchUrl = '$baseURl/sample.aac';

  var saveTo = File(saveToPath);

  if (saveTo.existsSync()) {
    saveTo.deleteSync();
  }

  final client = HttpClient();
  await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(fetchUrl)).then((request) {
    return request.close();
  }).then((response) async {
    var lengthReceived = 0;

    final contentLength = response.contentLength;
    print('expected: $contentLength');

    StreamSubscription<List<int>> subscription;
    subscription = response.listen(
      (newBytes) async {
        lengthReceived += newBytes.length;
        print('recieved $lengthReceived');
      },
      onDone: () async {
        await subscription.cancel();

        assert(contentLength == lengthReceived);

        completer.complete();
      },
      onError: (Object e, StackTrace st) async {
        await subscription.cancel();
        completer.completeError(e, st);
      },
      cancelOnError: true,
    );
  });

  await completer.future;
  print('finished');
}
```

Comment: The client will probably be staying open as you could use it again for another request. Try adding `client.close()` on line 36, to tell it you no longer need it.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks and merry xmas!